# Can't get Priority Queue/Comparator to Work For Custom Objects

Tags: java, queue, comparator, priority-queue

I know this question has been asked several times, but after searching through all the answers I don't think my problem is with using `poll()` during iteration, but perhaps my comparator is messed up. Every time I try to print the elements, they are in a random order. I understand that the priority queue internally is a tree, where the minimum element is the root. I figured iterating through and using `poll()` would work, but it didn't fix anything (before I tried to remove and making a custom iterator). I think something may be wrong with my comparator. I attached my code and the output [image: output]

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class scheduleCPU
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        jobCompare compare = new jobCompare();
        PriorityQueue<JobNode> jobQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(); // creating queue of job nodes

        int pJob = 0;
        String nJob = null;
        int lJob = 0;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
        
        Boolean exitInput = false;

        // taking in input
        while(exitInput != true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter priority, length, and name of job, enter 101 to stop entering jobs");
            pJob = userInput.nextInt();
            
            if(pJob ==101) 
            {
                userInput.close();
                break;
            }
            
            lJob = userInput.nextInt();
            
            nJob = userInput.next();
            
            JobNode currentJob = new JobNode(pJob, nJob, lJob); 
            jobQueue.add(currentJob);
        }
        
        Iterator<JobNode> jobIt = jobQueue.iterator();
        // to print the jobs
        while(!jobQueue.isEmpty()) 
        {
            // Arrays.sort(jobQueue.toArray());
            JobNode currentJob = jobQueue.poll();
            System.out.println(currentJob.name);
            // System.out.println(jobQueue);
        }
        
        // to process the jobs
        while(jobQueue.size()>0) 
        {
        JobNode current = jobQueue.remove();
        int jobLength = current.length;
        for(int i =0; i<jobLength;i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Job"+ current.name + " is " + ((i/jobLength)*100) + "% complete");
        }
        }
    }

}

class JobNode implements Comparable<JobNode>
{
    int priority;
    String name;
    int length;

    // constructor
    JobNode(int p, String n, int l)
    {
        priority = p;
        name = n;
        length = l;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(JobNode o)
    {
        return this.priority;
    }
}

class jobCompare implements Comparator<JobNode>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(JobNode j1, JobNode j2)
    {
        if (j1.priority < j2.priority)
            return 1;
        else if (j1.priority > j2.priority)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've incorrectly implemented `Comparable` interface in the `JobNode`.

Instead of comparing `priority` values of two `JobNode` instances (`this` and the argument `o`), you're simply returning the value of `priority` of `this` instance, ignoring the argument.

That's how `compareTo()` implementation might look like:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(JobNode o) {
    return Integer.compare(priority,  o.priority);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this when I get home later. I had a feeling I was using comparable wrong. I've always had trouble with interfaces in general.